# How to show $f(p, q|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta) = f(p|\alpha, \beta)f(q|\gamma, \delta)$ if $\alpha, \beta,\gamma,\delta$ are hyper-parameters?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, hyperparameter

Suppose we have that $f(p|\alpha, \beta)$ is a distribution of a random variable $P$ with hyperparameters $\alpha,\beta$, and that $f(q|\gamma, \delta)$ is a distribution of a random variable $Q$ with hyperparameters $\gamma, \delta$. Assume that $P$ and $Q$ are independent.

In this case, how do we explicitly show that:

$$
f(p, q|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta) = f(p|\alpha, \beta)f(q|\gamma, \delta)
$$?

It seems that since $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$ are all hyperparameters, then it doesn't make sense to factor $f(p, q|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)$ in the usual sense as they are not random variables. Hence, how does the factorization above "know" to associate $\alpha, \beta$ with $p$ and $\gamma, \delta$ with $q$?

In summary, how can we formally and rigorously prove the above? Can we start with:

$$
f(p, q|\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta) = \frac{f(p, q,\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)}{f(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)}
$$

and work it out from here? If so, it seems that $f(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta)$ doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let me note that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are not "hyperparameters". They are just ordinary parameters.

According to your first sentence, you are assuming that the marginal distribution of $P$ depends only on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and not on $\gamma$ or $\delta$. Similarly the marginal distribution of $Q$ depends only on $\gamma$ and $\delta$ and not on $\alpha$ or $\beta$. The notation you have used implies these assumptions.

You also assume that $P$ and $Q$ are independent, which is equivalent to assuming
$$f(p,q|\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=f_p(p|\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)f_q(q|\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta).$$
Your initial assumptions are that
$$f_p(p|\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=f_p(p|\alpha,\beta)$$
and
$$f_q(q|\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta)=f_q(q|\gamma,\delta)$$
Hence the result.